# Android project build fails on Bitrise with safeargs exception

Tags: android, bitrise, android-safe-args

My Android app runs normally on emulator, but the build is not succeeding on Bitrise.

It throws this exception:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: androidx.navigation.safeargs can only be used with an androidx project
```

I have the folowing plugins on my gradle (app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```

And these lines in gradle.properties

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

I'm wondering what's the reason for that exception.